# Invalid or no certificate authority found, using bundled information

Tags: php, facebook

I'm getting started with the facebook API.
I downloaded the example code from facebook, configured with my appID and secret keys.

```
<?php
   require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '...',
  'secret' => '....',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

// This call will always work since we are fetching public data.
$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');

?>
```

on localhost,the script work with no errors. But on host I getting the following error:

> Invalid or no certificate authority found, using bundled information

the **.crt** file was uploaded with success

one may point out my error? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I flagged the answer below prematurely.  I think I was able to clean up both answers, and make the consequences of the accepted answer clear to visitors.  I got a nice Link to the Past hat for my efforts too!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Set the option in CURL to point to your certificate file**

This option will tell CURL that your `fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt` file is in the same folder as your script.

```
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_CAINFO] = getcwd().'/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt';
```

In base_facebook.php line 844 curl_exec fails and the error is generated.  Then the script sets:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,
              dirname(__FILE__) . '/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt');
```

and tries again.

The Second time all is well, there is no problem it just makes a mess of your log

DO NOT use

`Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;`

Or a man-in-middle will be able to intercept your call!

Comment: This one is a much more appropriate answer than the one accepted! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @matt where will this snippet be added?

Comment: Note that I had to use __DIR__.'/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt' in AWS's PHP 5.5 app server.  I'm not sure why, but hint.

Comment: I didn't have the `.crt`, but found it here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/master/src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt

Comment: it worked for me! why why WHY WHY WHY WHY in the world I had to tell curl where the certificate chain resides... what were they thinking at facebook? Why it works on another domain of mine?

Answer (score 5):

**Disable the SSL security feature**

Though I don't recognize that exact error message, SSL problems when communicating with Facebook via the PHP SDK (and thus Curl) are common. Have you tried doing something like this?

```
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
```

This will disable the SSL "Verify Peer" security feature so that it stops generating the error message.

Comment: The referenced URL is no longer valid.  It appears that Facebook is no longer using the GitHub issue tracker.  They have an issue tracker at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs, but I'm not sure if they moved the referenced issue or not as I'm not sure the exact text and the search is not very good.

Comment: This answer is solving the error by disconnecting the feature.  The feature is there for a reason, and that reason is security.  Turning off the security feature to correct the mis-configured certificate file location is completely unacceptable.  -1, flagging.

Comment: This is always the wrong thing to do. It should not be marked as the correct answer. The one below is much better.

Comment: @JustinWarkentin: Changed

Answer (score 0):

get the latest plugin from http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-feed-grabber/ and replace the old chain certificate with new one

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the server config and everything seems fine. However I've seen a few other posts on the internet where users have fixed the issue by editing the following lines in

> "base_facebook.php"

/**
   * Default options for curl.
   */

```
public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'facebook-php-3.2',
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, (ADDED THIS LINE)
);
```

I've tested it and this now works, and it successfully posts to the Facebook page.

Cheers!

Mudassar Ali