# Facebook sdk getLoginUrl() method does not redirect already logged in users to authorize my app

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am using Facebook API for login with Facebook on my `codeigniter` app. It seems to be working fine except when the user is already logged in to Facebook but has never authorized my app. I redirect him to `getLoginUrl()` which should take him to authorize my app, but it never happens!

I am really lost and have been looking for solutions all around, any help would be appreciated

Here is my index function that is called on facebook login click:

```
 $data=array(
                'redirect_uri' => '/facebookcontroller/handle_facebook_login/',
                'scope' => 'publish_stream,email'
            );

            redirect($this->fbconnect->getLoginUrl($data));
```

And my `redirect_uri` is valid, I double checked.

So If the user is logged in, It will attempt to redirect him to `getloginurl()` which should take the user to authorize, but it doesn't. It goes straight to the `redirect_uri`.

Comment: [check this one out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760352/facebook-login-not-redirecting). Else what are you tried? Post some code for us :)

Comment: okay I posted my contoller's index method

Answer (score 1):

Do you check on user?

```
    // Init the Facebook SDK
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
           'appId'  => $app_id,
           'secret' => $app_secret,     
           'cookie' => true
    ));

    // Get the current user
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

if (!$user) {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope' => $scope,
            'redirect_uri' => $app_url,
            ));

            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    }
    else{        

    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

    // STUFF
    }
```

Comment: I am testing on my facebook account, I have previously authorized it, but erased all my facebook info from my database. I tried requesting the user info and it threw that error:
Invalid or no certificate authority found, using bundled information

It is worth mentioning that when it returns from facebook, it brings 2 variables: state, and code. Maybe I need to do further processing on it?

Comment: Okay. Maybe I think I know what is wrong. You have already AUTH your own account to the APP. You need to un-AUTH it. [go under your facebook settings, and delete the app auth](http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications)

Comment: Okay I did unAuthorize it, and then click and took me to the auth. page, but then it didnt register me, probably issues in my redirect_uri controller. Can you list the steps that I need to do after redirecting? do I get the access token, then set it and call the api('/me'), thanks

Comment: Now I get the access token, and set the access token, then call the api for the user info and I get: Invalid or no certificate authority found, using bundled information

Comment: facebook will give you an access token and set it automatically. After you have redirected, you should be able to gain access to the $facebook->api('/me');
Stuff like: echo "id: " . $user['id']; or $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

Comment: Try delete the setAccessToken. It also gave me trouble once

Comment: Okay I should be able to do that, and I've done it before but I am getting that error now : Invalid or no certificate authority found, using bundled information

Comment: [try what did guy did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374223/invalid-or-no-certificate-authority-found-using-bundled-information)

Comment: i tried deleting the setAccessToken, still the same error, It should be a curl problem, no?

Comment: Try clearing cookie and start over with auth and stuff. Else Try do what he did in other question

Comment: Okay I think it's fixed, at least for now, i updated the php sdk, and also there was a database error from my side. Thanks Pavenyourself for your effort.